# NavigationView always creates a new view

Tags: swiftui

I created a `NavigationView` and it works, but everytime I click on a `NavigationLink`, SwiftUI recreates the destination view and resets every property in it. See this example:

```
struct NavView: View {
    @State var selectionIndex: Int? = nil
    let views = [
        DestinationView(viewNumber: 1),
        DestinationView(viewNumber: 2),
        DestinationView(viewNumber: 3)
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: self.views[0], tag: 0, selection: $selectionIndex) {
                    Text("View 1")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: self.views[1], tag: 1, selection: $selectionIndex) {
                    Text("View 2")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: self.views[2], tag: 0, selection: $selectionIndex) {
                    Text("View 3")
                }
            }

            self.views[0]
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct DestinationView: View {
    @State var viewNumber: Int
    @State var count = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("View \(self.viewNumber)")
                .font(.largeTitle)
            Text("Count: \(self.count)")
            Button(action: {
                self.count += 1
            }) {
                Text("Increase counter")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this example clicking for example on the View1 link opens the View 1. Pressing the button increases the count property. If you then click on the View2 button and then back the View1 button, the count property will be zero again.

**EDIT**

I also tried not to store the views and create them directly in `body`, as suggested in the comments. Doesn't work either :(

```
struct NavView: View {
    @State var selectionIndex: Int? = nil

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView(viewNumber: 1), tag: 0, selection: $selectionIndex) {
                    Text("View 1")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView(viewNumber: 2), tag: 1, selection: $selectionIndex) {
                    Text("View 2")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView(viewNumber: 3), tag: 2, selection: $selectionIndex) {
                    Text("View 3")
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**
I also tried to store the views globally, I also tried with and without `tag:` and `selection:`

Answer (score 0):

Issue in your code is that every time you are by default initializing count to 0 whenever we are navigating to DestinationView so trick is we have to update count value and save it some where in NavView.

First of all you have to create `DestinationViewModel` to keep track of your updated count values like below

```
class DestinationViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var viewNumber: Int
    @Published var count: Int

    init(_ viewNumber: Int, count: Int) {
        self.viewNumber = viewNumber
        self.count = count
    }
}
```

Then you can access your `DestinationViewModel` in your `DestinationView`

```
struct DestinationView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: DestinationViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("View \(viewModel.viewNumber)")
                .font(.largeTitle)
            Text("Count: \(viewModel.count)")
            Button(action: {
                self.viewModel.count += 1
            }) {
                Text("Increase counter")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is your updated `NavView`

```
class DestinationViewModelContainer: ObservableObject {
    @Published var viewModels: [DestinationViewModel]
    init(_ viewModels: [DestinationViewModel]) {
        self.viewModels = viewModels
    }
}

struct NavView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModelContainer: DestinationViewModelContainer

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView().environmentObject(viewModelContainer.viewModels[0])) {
                    Text("View 1")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView().environmentObject(viewModelContainer.viewModels[1])) {
                    Text("View 2")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView().environmentObject(viewModelContainer.viewModels[2])) {
                    Text("View 3")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and Here you can call your `NavView` from below code

```
    let contentView = NavView().environmentObject(DestinationViewModelContainer([DestinationViewModel(1, count: 0), DestinationViewModel(2, count: 0),DestinationViewModel(3, count: 0)]))
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your detailed answer! I didn't try yet, but I'm pretty sure, that it will work. But the problem is, that this will only work for some properties and easy views, but imagine for example there is a ScrollView and the user scrolled to the end. This will reset as well and so you need to store this as well (no idea, how you could do this with SwiftUI). And there is also one big problem, that you can see in Xcode: Everytime pressing a NavigationLink increases the memory of the app, the old views will not get released.

Comment: @Lupurus have you found solution for this? I have the same problem to solve and already tired exact same approaches(tags, global storage of views, etc.) but nothing helps.

Comment: @SerhiiK Please read about StateObject which is introduced recently. It creates a reference type and object don't get deallocated incase of new instance.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasBhati thanks for your inputs, but the issue isn't about deallocating ObservableObject. Issue is about recreating view. Even '@State' doesn't persist for view storage.